# Matching records on multiple combinations of fields

Tags: sql, linq, algorithm, math, matching

I have a data table as follows

```
FName  SName  DOB  PCode   Addr1     
====   ==== ====== =====   =======  
Bob    Test 231280 S66TH   1 Test Lane  
Bobby  Test 240977 S66TH   2 Test Drive
Robert Test 240977 xxxxx   xxxxxx
Tim    Test 140977 S78YH   5 Hill Road
```

I am trying to write a function / SP that will accept Paramters FNAme, SName, Dob, PCode and Addr1.  I want to be able to match records where ANY 3 out of the 5 parameters are equal.  I'm not sure how to do this WITHOUT writing a long series of AND OR statements?  I would quite like the solution to be scalable too so if in future another column is added then 3 out of 6 must match (or even 4 out of 6).  I dont mind the query being represented by Linq either.

Essentially Im looking for a matching algorithm That can match x out of y pieces of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert true comparisons to 1, false comparisons to 0, add them all together, and test if the sum is at least 3. Something like

```
where (case FName when @FName then 1 else 0 end)
    + (case SName when @Sname then 1 else 0 end)
    + (case DOB   when @DOB   then 1 else 0 end)
    + (case PCode when @PCode then 1 else 0 end)
    + (case Addr1 when @Addr1 then 1 else 0 end)
    >= 3
```

Comment: That sounds like a potential solution.  Not easily scalable but ill look into it.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how the efficiency of this on 100K records plus?  I imagine the engine will have to get all records in order to perform this.

Comment: @Sheff yes, it will have to get all records in order to perform this.  And there is no way to optimize it.  Your standard "complex AND and OR statements" approach is similarly bad.  The second most efficient approach is a series of separate queries joined with appropriate UNION.  That loses to a series of separate queries designed to be fast, have no overlap, and joined with UNION ALL.  As is often the case efficiency and maintainability are opposed to each other.